# Finding an entire $g(z)$ such that $e^{g(z)}=\frac{e^{2z}-1}{\sin(iz)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Take $g(z)=\text{Log}\left(\dfrac{e^{2z}-1}{\sin(iz)}\right)$. Both $e^{2z}-1$ and $\sin(iz)$ have same (simple) zeroes, so $\dfrac{e^{2z}-1}{\sin(iz)}$ is an entire function with no zeroes. Therefore, $\text{Log}\left(\dfrac{e^{2z}-1}{\sin(iz)}\right)$ is entire since the composition of two analytic functions is analytic. But I'm not sure if this is correct since this seems too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are expected to find a simpler expression for $g$.

$\frac {e^{2z}-1} {\sin (iz)}=\frac {-2i (e^{2z}-1)} {e^{z}-e^{-z}}$. If you multiply numerator an denominator by $e^{z}$ you see that this becomes  $-2ie^{z}$ so just write $-2i$ as $e^{c}$ to finish.  [Answer: $g (z)=z+\ln 2 -i\frac {\pi} 2$].

Comment: You are too fast for most of us! Btw, I think it should be $\frac {e^{2z}-1} {\sin (iz)}=\frac {2i (e^{2z}-1)} {e^{-z}-e^{z}} = -2ie^z$

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comment. I hope it is clearer now.